# TextCtrl aren't aligning correctly in Python

Tags: python, wxpython

This is my code:

```
    label_1 = wx.StaticText(self,-1,_("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"))
    label_2 = wx.StaticText(self,-1,_("xxxxxxx:         "))
    self.item1= wx.TextCtrl(self,-1,"",style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
    self.item2= wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "", style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
    self.item1.SetMinSize((200,-1))
    self.item2.SetMinSize((200,-1))
    sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    sizer_2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    sizer_1.Add(label_1,0,wx.RIGHT|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL,10)
    sizer_1.Add(self.item1,0,wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)
    sizer_2.Add(label_2,0,wx.RIGHT|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL,10)
    sizer_2.Add(self.item2,0,wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL) 
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer.Add(sizer_1,0,wx.ALL,4)  
    sizer.Add(sizer_2,0,wx.ALL,4) 
    self.SetSizer(sizer)
    self.Layout()
```

Which gives:

[image]

Why the `textctrl` aren't in the same distance from the labels? The labels have same length, the textctrl should "start" from their end.
How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the other answer and commentary about making it work with `BoxSizer`, in my mind this example is crying out for a grid sizer.  It will automatically align columns due to the nature of the grid, rather than needing the programmer to pound box sizers into submission.  Here is your example ported to use a `wx.FlexGridSizer`:

```
import wx

class Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(Panel, self).__init__(*args, **kw)

        # Create widgets
        label_1 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:")
        label_2 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "xxxxxxx:")
        self.item1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "", size=(200,-1), style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        self.item2 = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "", size=(200,-1), style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)

        # put them into a grid sizer
        fgs = wx.FlexGridSizer(2,2, 10,10)
        fgs.Add(label_1, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)
        fgs.Add(self.item1)
        fgs.Add(label_2, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)
        fgs.Add(self.item2)

        # put a margin around the whole thing
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(fgs, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Layout() 

app = wx.App()
frm = wx.Frame(None, title="foobar")
pnl = Panel(frm)
frm.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

wxPython defaults will make widgets fit to their best size. The best way to get pairs of static text controls and text controls to line up is to set both of the StaticText widgets to a specific size via their size parameter. Something like this should suffice:

```
size = (150, -1)
label_1 = wx.StaticText(self,-1, label="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", size=size)
label_2 = wx.StaticText(self,-1, label="xxxxxxx:", size=size)
```

As you can see, this also removes the need to add padding to the second label's string.

Alternatively, you can use a `GridSizer` (or one of its variants) and that will have the same effect.

Comment: Also, using the default font the space is not as wide as the 'x', so making things the same width with spaces in your text editor (which likely uses a monospace font) is not going work in the application where the font is not monospaced.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll there is an error:  label_1 = wx.StaticText(self,-1, label="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", size=size)
TypeError: ugettext() got an unexpected keyword argument 'size'

Comment: @RobinDunn But the code has: self.item1.SetMinSize((200,-1)) self.item2.SetMinSize((200,-1)) why isn't that enougth?

Comment: @SMW - Not sure how it could not have `size` as a parameter. It's listed in the documentation - https://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.StaticText-class.html and I know I've used it many times.

Comment: Based on the error message I would guess that you are passing size to `_()`, not `wx.StaticText()`.  Also you are calling `SetMinSize` on the TextCtrls, not the StaticTextCtrls, so they will not have their min size set, so the sizer will only use their natural size.  Finally, passing a size value in the constructor of most controls (not all widgets, but most controls) will also set the min size, so that makes things a little simpler.